# Overlapping rows - Difficult to explain - Bootstrap 3

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

I have no idea how to explain this without just showing you the picture of what I'm trying to achieve:

[image: http://i.imgur.com/lQKDxRx.jpg]

The problem I have is the search box isn't fixed height, and I might even want to add other items on the left hand side. Each result ideally needs to be its own DIV.

How do I make the height of the DIVs in the left on hand column completely irrelevant to the height of the search results?

I hope this makes sense.

**EDIT: Sorry if I didn't explain it well, basically result 3 jumps over to the left once it has passed the search box. I need them to continue in line. Also the classes for all the result DIV's need to be the same.**

Comment: Any code or fiddle will be helpful...

Comment: If you'd actually tried this, you would notice that the heights are _already_ irrelevant

Comment: Thanks. I have tried it, as soon as the "search box" ends. result 3 jumps over to the left.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

HTML

```
<div class="row">

 <div class="col-md-4">  <!-- Your left box -->

 </div>

 <div class="col-md-8"> 

    <div class="results"> <!-- Your right Box1 -->
    </div>

    <div class="results"> <!-- Your right Box2 -->
    </div>

    <div class="results"> <!-- Your right Box3 -->
    </div>

 </div>

</div>
```

CSS

```
.results {

     width:  100%;
}
```

If you want to add other box into the first collumn use this

```
<div class="row">

 <div class="col-md-4"> 

    <div>  <!-- Your left box -->
    </div>

    <div>  <!-- Your other box -->
    </div>

    ...

 </div>

 <div class="col-md-8"> 

    <div class="results"> <!-- Your right Box1 -->
    </div>

    <div class="results"> <!-- Your right Box2 -->
    </div>

    <div class="results"> <!-- Your right Box3 -->
    </div>

 </div>

</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

I did it this way.

```
<div class="container">
 <div class="row">
  <div class="col-sm-3">search box</div>
  <div class="col-sm-9">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-sm-12">result 1</div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-sm-12">result 2</div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-sm-12">result 3</div>
    </div>
  </div>
 </div>
</div>
```

Comment: this looks like a good approach, will bare that in mind for the future. Thanks!

Comment: May be a good Way to say thanks is to give a upvote if it is helpful. @absdigital

Comment: I'd love to but I don't have enough reputation to upvote apparently. As soon as I have, I will be sure to come back and vote.

Comment: Well I'll do it for you :)

Answer (score 0):

“How do I make the height of the DIVs in the left on hand column completely irrelevant to the height of the search results?”

It is already per default. The hard thing would be to match the heights of elements in different columns (which is not possible in Twitter Bootstrap 3 without using JS as the grid system is based on floats, not e.g. on flexbox).